# "Binding implicitly has an 'any' type" over function type union but not individual function types

Tags: typescript

I just came across something that I don't understand.

With the following code in strict mode :

```
type F1 = (arg: { x: number }) => any
type F2 = (...args: Array<any>) => any
type F3 = F1 | F2 

let f1: F1 = ({ x }) => x*2
let f2: F2 = ({ x }) => x*2
let f3: F3 = ({ x }) => x*2 // Binding element 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type".
```

***Only*** the `x` from `f3` is underlined in red and says *"Binding element 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type"*.

Why is that ? Isn't the `x` from `f2` also implicitly `any` ?

**[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgjFAvFAFAQwE4HMBcUDeAHngHYCuAtgEYQZQC%20AlEgHxRokgBQoksATElQA6UZiwBnPAEEMGNCAA8HEC2aI2KnuGgwAzEPhQAPgKhcuAGwjAoAMzh4jyFPiiEG6toQBU-Kzb2-E6CLm4eTKzufgG2dnpOBmHunlG%20-kA)**

Comment: "Isn't the `x` from `f2` also implicitly `any`?" No, because in this case, it's **explicitly** `any` since you supplied the argument type.

Comment: @Aplet123 How so ? Furthermore, if `F2` is explicit and `F1` also, why isn't the union of both ?